# Given $f(x) = x^{1/3}$, show that $f \in BV[0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

I'm learning about functions of bounded variations and need some help with this problem:

> Given $f(x) = x^{1/3}, x \in [0, 1]$ show that $f \in BV[0, 1]$.

**My work and thoughts:**

We know that given any function $f: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, differentiable on the interval $[a, b]$, if $|f'(x)| \leq M \ \forall x \in [a, b]$ (i.e. if the derivative of $f$ is bounded on the closed interval) then $f \in BV[a, b]$.

Considering our function  $f(x) = x^{1/3}$ we have $f'(x) = \frac{1}{3} x^{-2/3} = \frac{1}{3x^{2/3}}$. The function $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $0$. How can I work around this problem to bound the derivative for all $x \in [0, 1]$?

Comment: Forget the derivative! This is trivial from the _definition_ of BV. (Hint: The reason it's trivial is that $f$ is non-decreasing...)

Comment: Or you can just show the derivative is absolutely integrable. I.e., compute $\int_0^1|f'(x)|dx$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I think I got it! Since $f(x)$ is a monotonically increasing function on [0, 1], then by definition is it of bounded variation on that closed interval (all monotonic functions are of bounded variation). Is that the correct application?

Comment: Yes, all monotonc functions on $[0,1]$ are BV. No, that's not "by definition", it's a very easy _theorem_. Which you should be able to prove, starting with the definition of BV.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you for this clarification and helpful explanation.